# Combining multiple lines between two patterns

Tags: awk

On HP-Unix:
Input file looks like:

```
BEGIN_BLOCK
random_line1
random_line_2
END_BLOCK
junk lines...
BEGIN_BLOCK
random_line1
random_line2
random_line3
END_BLOCK
and so on ..
```

Desired output:

```
BEGIN_BLOCK random_line1 random_line_2 END_BLOCK
BEGIN_BLOCK random_line1 random_line2 random_line3 END_BLOCK
```

Basically, put all lines between `BEGIN_BLOCK` and `END_BLOCK` into a single line.

Note: the text `BEGIN_BLOCK`, `END_BLOCK` will not occur in the random_lines.
I am a newbie and could not quite figure out how to make `awk` produce this output.

Comment: the input files -- BEGIN_BLOCK, random_lie1, .. etc are on different lines -- this site is removing the CRLFs! Rather confusing, as my question is about removing end-line chars.

Comment: [edit] your question to show what the output would be for the non-trivial cases, including a) 2 BEGIN_BLOCKs  before an END_BLOCK, b) 2 END_BLOCKS after a BEGIN_BLOCK, c) a BEGIN_BLOCK but no END_BLOCK, d) an END_BLOCK but no BEGIN_BLOCK, e) nested blocks (BEGIN_BLOCK ... BEGIN_BLOCK ... END_BLOCK ... END_BLOCK), f) END_BLOCK after BEGIN_BLOCK on the same line, g) BEGIN_BLOCK after END_BLOCK on the same line, h) both delimiters in the middle of other text.

Comment: Oh, and also replace the ambiguous word "pattern" with either "string" or "regexp" whichever it is you actually mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this relatively simply with a single variable to track whether you are in-a-block where you should output the current record appending it to the current line, or if you are between blocks (not in a block) were you should skip printing the record.

You can use three rules, the first triggered when `/^BEGIN_BLOCK/` where you output the record, set `inblock=1` and skip to the next record. The second just tests if `inblock` is set, and if so appends the record to the current line of output, and finally a rule triggered when `/^END_BLOCK/` is encountered, where you complete the line of output and set `inblock=0`.

For example:

```
awk -v inblock=0 '
    /^BEGIN_BLOCK/  { printf "%s", $0; inblock=1; next }
    inblock         { printf " %s", $0 }
    /^END_BLOCK/    { printf "\n"; inblock=0 }
' file
```

(**note:** you use `printf` instead of `print` so you have end-of-line control, choosing when not to, and when to output the `'\n'`. The `END_BLOCK` rule could simply `print ""` which would be equivalent)

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample input in `file`, you can select-copy and middle-mouse-paste the above into an xterm in the directory containing `file` and obtain:

```
$ awk -v inblock=0 '
>     /^BEGIN_BLOCK/  { printf "%s", $0; inblock=1; next }
>     inblock         { printf " %s", $0 }
>     /^END_BLOCK/    { printf "\n"; inblock=0 }
> ' file
BEGIN_BLOCK random_line1 random_line_2 END_BLOCK
BEGIN_BLOCK random_line1 random_line2 random_line3 END_BLOCK
```

You can write this in a more condensed and less readable way -- several different ways. You can use string concatenation to build a single string with all information between `BEGIN_BLOCK` and `END_BLOCK` and simply output once instead of appending each record to the line of output, etc.. Many different ways to *skin-the-cat* in `awk`.

For example, using string concatenation, you could do:

```
awk -v inblock=0 '
    /^BEGIN_BLOCK/  { inblock=1 }
    inblock         { s=(length(s) ? s" "$0 : $0) }
    /^END_BLOCK/    { print s; s=""; inblock=0 }
' file
```

(same output -- but note, all string concatenation occurs in the `inblock` rule)

But what if you had empty `BEGIN_BLOCK` and `END_BLOCK` lines or lines where `BEGIN_BLOCK` and `END_BLOCK` were out of order? Then your output would concatenate it all together. You can always refine your `awk` scripts to deal with additional caveats by adding additional logic -- in small steps. For example:

```
awk -v inblock=0 '
    /^BEGIN_BLOCK/  { inblock=1 }
    inblock         { s=(match($0,/BEGIN_BLOCK/) ? $0 : s" "$0) }
    /^END_BLOCK/    { if (inblock && s != "BEGIN_BLOCK END_BLOCK") print s; s=""; inblock=0 }
' file
```

Here output is only printed if there are additional lines between `BEGIN_BLOCK` and `END_BLOCK` and only between opening and closing `BEGIN_BLOCK` and `END_BLOCK` tags. It would handle a horribly messed up, and out of order `file` such as:

```
$ cat file
BEGIN_BLOCK
random_line1
random_line_2
END_BLOCK
junk lines...
BEGIN_BLOCK
END_BLOCK
END_BLOCK
END_BLOCK
BEGIN_BLOCK
stuff_in_bad_begin
BEGIN_BLOCK
random_line1
random_line2
random_line3
END_BLOCK
...
```

If you are just learning `awk`, see [StackOverflow AWK tag-info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) and my favorite [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents)

Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk,

```
awk ' /BEGIN_BLOCK/,/END_BLOCK/ { printf("%s ",$0); next } { print "" } END { print "" } '

$ cat manoj.txt
BEGIN_BLOCK
random_line1
random_line_2
END_BLOCK
junk lines...
BEGIN_BLOCK
random_line1
random_line2
random_line3
END_BLOCK
$ awk ' /BEGIN_BLOCK/,/END_BLOCK/ { printf("%s ",$0); next } { print "" } END { print "" } ' manoj.txt
BEGIN_BLOCK random_line1 random_line_2 END_BLOCK
BEGIN_BLOCK random_line1 random_line2 random_line3 END_BLOCK
$
```

You can pipe it to another awk and remove the blank lines.

```
awk ' /BEGIN_BLOCK/,/END_BLOCK/ { printf("%s ",$0); next } { print "" } END { print "" } ' manoj.txt | awk 'NF'
```